# How to update the count column of a pandas DataFrame from multiple DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 5 CSV files, each one with size 7 GB, with the same structure and I need to obtain only one DataFrame with unique IDs.

The structure is, actually, really simple since each CSV file is composed by just 2 columns, `userID` and a `count` column of type `int`.

The problem is that once I load the first DataFrame, with the values in the column `userID` unique for each user, the following DataFrame may have the same `userID` found in the first one.

In case this happens, I would sum the two `count` values and keep just one of the two records.

For example:

```
df1:

"user"  "count"
  X        3
  Y        4
  Z        8
  W        2
```

and in the following one:

```
df2:

"user"  "count"
  X        2
  W        10
  Z        5
  T        6
```

In this example, I explain the situation with just 2 DataFrames, but in my case, they are 5. The result I would obtain is described in the following DataFrame:

```
df_res:

"user"  "count"
  X        5
  Y        4
  Z        13
  W        12
  T        6
```

What I tried up to now is:

```
import pandas as pd


users = {}

for path in ["A.csv", "B.csv", "C.csv", "D.csv", "E.csv"]:
    current = pd.read_csv(path)  # here the columns are "user", "counts" and others
    _users = pd.DataFrame(columns=["user", "counts"])
    if users:
        _users = _users.append(users)

    _users = _users.append(current.loc[:, ["user", "counts"]], ignore_index=True)

    users = _users.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all individual csv files in one dataframe and then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

all=[]
for path in ["A.csv", "B.csv"]:
    current = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s+')
    all.append(current[["user", "counts"]])
df = pd.concat(all, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df_res = df.groupby('user', as_index=False).counts.sum()
```

Result:

```
  user  counts
0    T       6
1    W      12
2    X       5
3    Y       4
4    Z      13
```

---

Update for large csv files using [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html):

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('*.csv', sep='\s+', usecols=["user", "counts"])
df_res = df.groupby('user').counts.sum().reset_index().compute()
```

Result:

```
  user  counts
0    W      12
1    X       5
2    Y       4
3    Z      13
4    T       6
```

Comment: It's not so simple, I don't say this before, but the files are 7 GB each, so I think that, for this solution, I'd get a `MemoryError`..

Comment: in this case you should have a look at [`dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html)

Comment: you could also do the groupby in the loop after each new csv so that you don't need to hold all files in memory and only then process them